# Complete the square doesn't work here.

Tags: integration

In this substitution, I tried the method of complete the square, but at the end the answer is not correct. I'm totally sure that the answer is: $\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{7}\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{7}(2x-1)}{7})+C$, and I try different techniques, but I can´t get this result.

This is the Integral:

$\int\frac{dx}{x^2-x+2}$

Comment: Look at my generalised answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394731/integral-of-frac1x2x1-and-frac1x2-x1/1394740#1394740) and check

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{x^2-x+2}&=\int\frac{dx}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{7}{4}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{7}}\right)+C
\end{align*}

Since $$\int\frac{du}{u^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+C$$