# Where was my mistake (integration by trig-substitution problem)?

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I am attempting to solve the problem

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}$$

First, I complete the square, then factor out a $\frac {3}{4}$:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\frac{3}{4}(\frac{4}{3}(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+1)}$$

Let $u = \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}(x+\frac{1}{2})$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$dx = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} du$$

Thus, we now have the integral:

$$\frac{4}{3} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \int \frac{du}{u^2+1}$$

Let $u = \tan \theta$

$$du = \sec^2\theta \ d\theta$$

What follows is obvious now, and the solution should be:

$$\frac{4}{3} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \theta + C$$

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}(u)$$

Thus, the final solution is:

$$\frac{4}{3} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac 4 3} \left(x+\frac 1 2 \right)\right) + C$$

However, according to online calculator integral-calculator, the answer is:

$$\frac 2 {\sqrt 3} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3} \right)+C$$

Any indication as to where my mistake falls would be very beneficial.

Comment: The two answers you've given are equal.  You just need to do some algebra to see it.  For instance, $\frac{4}{3} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(x + 1/2) = \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Ah, I see. The calculator said they weren't but that its answer checking service is unreliable. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral of $\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$ and$\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394731/integral-of-frac1x2x1-and-frac1x2-x1)

Comment: @zwim Most certainly not a duplicate. Here the OP has already figure out how to find the integral, and is only having problems simplifying his answer to match what we was supposed to get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only mistake appears to be a failure to notice that $\displaystyle \frac{4}{3} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac 4 3} \left(x+\frac 1 2 \right)\right) $ is exactly the same thing as $ \displaystyle \frac 2 {\sqrt 3} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3} \right).$

First you have
$$
\frac 4 3 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 3} 2 = \frac{4\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3\sqrt 3 \cdot 2} = \frac 2 {\sqrt 3}.
$$
And then
$$
\sqrt{\frac 4 3} \left( x + \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 2 {\sqrt 3} \left( x + \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 3} (2x+1).
$$

Answer (score 7):

> **This answer was posted prior to an edit made by the OP.**

Note that we have

$$x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4\ne \frac34 \left(\frac43 (x+1/2)^2+\frac34 \right)=x^2+2+5/2$$

Comment: My apologies, I meant for it to be $\int \frac{dx}{\frac{3}{4}(\frac{4}{3}(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+1)}$